# Python Find all subarrays of given array. (what mistakes have I done )

Tags: python, loops, range

```
def findSubarray(self, arrayList):
    newArray = []
    for i in range(len(arrayList)):
        for n in range(i, len(arrayList)):
            newArray.append(arrayList[i:n])
    print(newArray)
```

The input I tried is [1,-1,3,5,7]. But the output is so wrong, all the subarrays don't have the last element 7, I wonder what mistakes have I done?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `arrayList1[i:n]` does not include the `n` index. For example :  `arrayList1:3]` will only consider `1` and `2` index and output `[-1, 3]`

Try : add `n+1`

```
def findSubarray( arrayList):
newArray = []
for i in range(len(arrayList)):
    for n in range(i, len(arrayList)):
        newArray.append(arrayList[i:n+1])
print(newArray)

findSubarray( arrayList=[1,-1,3,5,7])
```